# Where can I watch My Hero Academia Season 3 for free?

Tags: my-hero-academia, streaming-sites

I'm looking for a **legal** streaming site where I can watch the whole *My Hero Academia* series for free. But for now, season 3 is enough.

Edit: I'm from India.

Comment: @RigaCrypto i don't really want to post the link on the main site here but i've posted my comment on why i think the site is illegal [in the Maid Cade](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54638407#54638407)

Comment: @Memor-X Yeah, had a hunch it wasn't legal, but at least it has a good amount of anime series that others sites dont have. I don't have many options to watch anime from where I'm from.

Answer (score 3):

you can find all 4 current Seasons on [Crunchy Roll](https://www.crunchyroll.com/my-hero-academia). I believe they are all English Subbed however only checked one episode of Season 3.

Be aware that Crunchy Roll does employ Geoblocking on some series. i am in Australia, not using a VPN and am not being blocked so availability might depend on where you are and current licencing agreements

Comment: Crunchyroll isn't available in my region. I've tried Crunchyroll other times too, but it didn't work. I think the reason was my country.

Comment: @SujalMotagi you might want to edit your question as to what region you are in. alternatively you might be able to use a VPN to get around any regional/geoblocking